# Error 500 cuando genero zip con php - ziparchive

Tags: php, zip

estoy intentando generar un fichero zip con php, he descargado una demo que funciona pero al implementarlo en mi servidor me devuelve error 500, a que se puede deber?

Aqui os dejo el código.

```
function agregar_zip($dir, $zip) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($da = opendir($dir)) {
      while (($archivo = readdir($da)) !== false) {

        if (is_dir($dir . $archivo) && $archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
          echo "<strong>Creando directorio: $dir$archivo</strong><br/>";
          agregar_zip($dir . $archivo . "/", $zip);

        } elseif (is_file($dir . $archivo) && $archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
          echo "Agregando archivo: $dir$archivo <br/>";
          $zip->addFile($dir . $archivo, $dir . $archivo);
        }
      }
      closedir($da);
    }
  }
}

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$dir = 'fuente/'; //Dir a comprimir
$rutaFinal = "archivos/"; //Dir donde se almacenará

if(!file_exists($rutaFinal)){
  mkdir($rutaFinal);
}

$archivoZip = "pruebazip.zip"; //nombre del fichero.zip

if ($zip->open($archivoZip, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {
  agregar_zip($dir, $zip);
  $zip->close();

  rename($archivoZip, "$rutaFinal/$archivoZip");

  if (file_exists($rutaFinal. "/" . $archivoZip)) {
    echo "Proceso Finalizado!! <br/><br/>
                Descargar: <a href='$rutaFinal/$archivoZip'>$archivoZip</a>";
  } else {
    echo "Error, archivo zip no ha sido creado!!";
  }
}
```

Comment: puedes revisar el log de error de apache para ver en que estas fallando.

Comment: El servidor es nginx, el log me muestra esto:

Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found, no encuentra la clase, entonces es que no está habilitado?

Comment: Si, puede que no este habilitado. crea un `phpinfo()` y revisa, si te falta la extensión en instalala dependiendo a la versión de php que tenga

Comment: En zip me pone:

Zip Pierre-Alain Joye, Remi Collet
ZIP -based phar archives enabled
gzip compression enabled
bzip2 compression disabled (install pecl/bz2)

Comment: que SO tienes y que php tienes?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 y php 7.0

Comment: Revisa esta liga https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988022/php-enable-bz2-extension-in-php-ini

Comment: Lo pude solucionar instalando el paquete php7.0-zip

Comment: Comenta tu solucion en el área de respuestas y marcala como correcta! Esto para que pueda ayudar a la comunidad